# Is React.ComponentType<Props> part of Flow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, redux

I'm using React Redux and reading some of the source code here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-redux/index.d.ts

It refers to `ComponentType` in the following code:

```
import {
...
ComponentType,
...
} from 'react';
```

I've been trying to find documentation to understand what ComponentType is, and have only found this doc, in which it describes `React.ComponentType<Props>`: https://flow.org/en/docs/react/types/#toc-react-componenttype

This ^^ is the documentation for Flow. So my question is:

Is `ComponentType` part of Flow? In the code snippet above it's just imported from 'react', so I assumed it's part of React and wouldn't be associated with Flow, since Flow is a separate type checker. Is `ComponentType` from 'react' different from `React.ComponentType<Props>` in Flow? Or are they the same thing, and components imported from 'react' can be defined within Flow? What am I misunderstanding?

Thanks!

Comment: ComponentType  is just a type definition that is used by Flow. Flow was created by the React team thats why its included in React itself. Its basically the same as TypeScripts @types/react type definitions but since Type Script wasnt built by FB its types are not included by default.

Comment: @GifCo thanks for your reply. A few follow up questions based on what you said:
1) I know React was created by Facebook, so what's the difference between "the React team" you mentioned, and Facebook itself?
2) What do you mean by "a type definition that is used by Flow"? If I'm using React but not Flow, is ComponentType still a thing?
3) You mentioned that Typescript's "types are not included by default" but that they are "included in React itself". What is the difference between "included by default" and "included in React itself"?

Thanks!

Comment: So with Flow or Typescript that adds type checking to JS you are defining types for all your variables and components. You dont want to have to create type definitions for every react base component every HTML element that you might use ect. So people from Flow or TypeScript create these generic type definitions that you can then import. Then you only have to type props and state for your own custom components. The React team are just specific employees at FB that maintain React. But FB would have lots of different dev teams, not sure if React and Flow team are exactly the same people.

Comment: So with ComponentType, I import it from 'react' but I'm not knowingly using Flow anywhere. Is Flow built into React?

Comment: The flow type checking compiler is not built in you have to install it with NPM. Only the type definitions are included with the core React package. If you arnt using Flow just remove that import, unless some other package/component you are using requires it everything should work fine. If you do need it for some reason you will just get an error saying you are missing that import and you can add it back.